# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit'

Tags: python, 16.10, pyqt

I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, and python3 code that was previously working, does not work anymore, i.e.:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit'
>>>
```

Package `python3-pyqt4` is installed.

Why is this, and what other packages are needed for this to work?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyside.qtwebkit`

Comment: hm... but I want applications that use `PyQt4.QtWebKit` to work. Why is this changed in 16.10?

Comment: `python3-pyside.qtwebkit - Qt 4 WebKit module - Python3 bindings` is what you wanted right? Did the above package solved your issue?

Comment: No. I don't want to use PySide and re-factor all code. I want my Python3 applications that use PyQt4 WebKit, to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `PyQt4.QtWebKit` package got removed in Ubuntu 16.10, probably because both PyQt4 and QtWebKit are long unmaintained.

Comment: PyQt5.QtWebKit is available, PyQt4.QtWebKit is not

Comment: Whoops, indeed - thanks, edited! Though at some future Ubuntu release, I'd expect PyQt5.QtWebKit to be removed as well.