# native FAF on ubuntu (QtWebKit on ubuntu 17.04+)

Tags: software-installation, 17.04, pyqt, qt4, qtwebkit

I'm trying to run FAF (natively) in conjunction with FA (through wine)

(due to the views this post receives and to how much the methods have updated I've decided to update this question for it to answer as well as ask. check revision history of this post for the process to finding the old method to run the python client and the old guides)

---

### Beta-state Java Client :

[image]

use this script : **(updated 3/12/2019)**

https://github.com/tatsujb/installFAFscript

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEWUEoQ8Q4k

---

### Python client : (NOW OBSOLETE)

[image: working FAF]

How to: compile [this python app](https://github.com/FAForever/client) (FAF) from source :

up and running thanks to @edwinksl 's "Python 3 with PyQt5" guide. marked him as solution.
good job!

#### Update (31/1/2018)

Sorry I took so long to update this post. it's gotten 7000 views! it really deserves up-to-date info.

Since I asked a lot has happened. FAF now has more or less linux support. they even have a wiki to installing it (and per distro!) :

https://wiki.faforever.com/index.php?title=Setting_Up_FAF_Linux#Debian.2FUbuntu

it's not guaranteed to fit your needs, more can be found by digging in : http://forums.faforever.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4507

right now the wiki isn't all that up to date.

for awhile I could get faf to run with native python, no virtualenv needed but QT's aver changing dependencies and package composition as well as the
FAF usage of them has broken that again ... temporarily I hope !

rest assured I've got it running personally and I'm here to offer solace (try skipping steps 6 & 7 first they may be unneeded ):

1. Install some prerequisites : `sudo apt update && sudo apt install wget PyQt5.QtMultimedia python3-idna python3-semantic-version python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine`
2. `cd Downloads && wget https://github.com/FAForever/client/archive/0.16.1.tar.gz` (or whichever release is latest at https://github.com/FAForever/client/releases/ )
3. extract (for this example I'll extract to home) (`cd Downloads/ && mv client-0.16.1.tar.gz ~/ && cd && tar -zxf client-0.16.1.tar.gz && mv client-0.16.1 faf-client && rm client-0.16.1.tar.gz`)
4. `cd fafclient/` : move to the working dirrectory
5. `sed -i 1,1d requirements.txt` : removes cxFreeze from the requirements (it's not required and it will kill compile)
6. `virtualenv -p python3 faf`
7. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
8. `sudo wget https://github.com/FAForever/uid/releases/download/v4.0.5/faf-uid -O /usr/bin/faf-uid` : downloads login binary and : `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/faf-uid` allows it to be executed by faf.
9. `touch res/RELEASE-VERSION && echo "0.16.1" >> res/RELEASE-VERSION` : fulfills faf's final requirement : a release version file.

now it should run but for the heck of it let's make a runner :

```
touch FAF.sh
echo "#! /bin/bash" >> FAF.sh
echo "cd /home/t/faf-client" >> FAF.sh
echo "python3 src/__main__.py" >> FAF.sh
chmod +x FAF.sh
```

then `./FAF.sh` to run FAF.

Cheers!

Comment: See https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git . If you still have a problem, contact the qtwebkit maintainers directly.

Comment: `t@tsu:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: So put source uri in - https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list

Comment: i ran evey command on that page except for the "Convenience packages (Ubuntu 11.10 -- 12.10 only)" and yet the FAF crash issue persists. and also `t@tsu:~$ whereis qtwebkit
qtwebkit:`

Comment: It is unfortuinate, but I have found the qt apps are difficult / frustrating to compile when I have had to do so in the past. File a bug report upstream.

Comment: ok.
is the fact that after adding the sources and updating. when I do :
`sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default`
I get the message ending with 
`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` caused by me having all these random compiles qt and whatnot or is it something else? packages aren't really broken since upgrade and install still work

Comment: "It depends" building qt has been a pain as it is in rapid development and the dependencies are not always available in any specific version of Ubuntu. You will need to debug that warning though.

Comment: also since I'm new to this I don't know where that bug reporting would be. may I have  a link please?

Comment: http://wiki.qt.io/Reporting_Bugs

Comment: is it a QT Web BRowser bug or a QT bug I'm going with QT

Comment: There are both python (python2) and python3 versions. Are you installing the correct one. Ubuntu is in the process of converting from python2 to python3, so depending on version of Ubuntu you may have one or the other or both. But can install either from all versions of Ubuntu. And then which python is program based on?

Comment: this program is definitely python2 ... as per why i have to use virtualenv. It's suicide to compile python2 on ubuntu 11+ as far as i know.

Comment: @oldfred hey i've updated the OP could you tell me what you think of this new approach. it was suggested to me by the people of QT bug report but I can't get it to work either.

Comment: I have never compiled anything. But I think I am using this and have it installed using synaptic from Ubuntu repository. python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit

Comment: @oldfred in my OP i said i did this. this did not yeild results. perhaps it means qtwebkit needs to be available virtualenv side?

Comment: Never used virtualenv, so do not know.

Comment: @tatsu I think I managed to get QtWebKit working but I don't have the FAF game, so I can't fully verify this works. Let me try to get a chatroom set up so we can discuss.

Comment: @tatsu Meanwhile I wrote an answer. Give it a try and see if it helps.

Comment: @tatsu Your latest error log shows that `_clientwindow.py` is trying to import `QtWebKit` from `PyQt4`, which is the cause of the problem. Try importing `QtWebKit` from `PySide` instead.

Comment: @edwinksl I'm completely noob on this matter. how do I accomplish that x) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: the steps for Python 3 with PyQt5 are proven to work while the steps for Python 2 with PyQt4 and PySide are still experimental.

## Python 3 with PyQt5 (proven to work)

It appears that the `474-feature-py3` branch of the FAForever/client GitHub repository uses Python 3 with PyQt5, which contains QtWebKit. Therefore, using this branch is the most straightforward solution. Note that PyQt5 (but not PyQt4) can in fact be installed with `pip`, so that makes things way more convenient.

Steps for Python 3 with PyQt5:

1. `cd` into a directory of your choice, which will be `~/Desktop/temp` for the purpose of writing this answer, `git clone` the FAForever/client GitHub repository and `git checkout` the `474-feature-py3` branch:

   ```
   mkdir ~/Desktop/temp
   cd ~/Desktop/temp
   git clone https://github.com/FAForever/client.git faf-client
   cd faf-client
   git checkout 474-feature-py3
   ```
2. Create and activate a virtualenv for Python 3 (the default is Python 3.5 for Ubuntu 17.04) and force-upgrade `pip` just to make sure it is up-to-date:

   ```
   virtualenv venv -p python3  # replace python3 with python3.6 if you want to use Python 3.6 instead
   source venv/bin/activate
   pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
   ```
3. Use `pip` to install `PyQt5` and from `requirements.txt`:

   ```
   pip install PyQt5
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
4. Download the `faf-uid` binary into `faf-client/lib` and make it executable:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/FAForever/uid/releases/download/v4.0.4/faf-uid -O lib/faf-uid
   chmod +x lib/faf-uid
   ```
5. Run `python` on `src/__main__.py`:

   ```
   python src/__main__.py
   ```

## Python 2 with PyQt4 and PySide (experimental)

It looks like I may have figured out how to import the `QtWebKit` module, but I don't have the FAF game installed, so I cannot fully verify that this works and therefore this answer is a work in progress.

In a nutshell, I used `apt` to install `python-qt4`, which does *not* have the `QtWebKit` module. I created and activated a virtualenv without using the `--system-site-packages` option and used `pip` to install `PySide`, which does have the `QtWebKit` module. I then symlinked the appropriate system libraries and files for PyQt4 into the virtualenv. Then I made a couple of changes to `faf-client/src` to import the `QtWebKit` module from `PySide`. This solution is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/28850104/486919, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36887302/486919 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616466/486919.

Steps:

1. Install `python-qt4`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install python-qt4
   ```
2. `cd` into a directory of your choice, which will be `~/Desktop/temp` for the purpose of writing this answer, `git clone` my version of the repository and `git checkout` the `patch` branch:

   ```
   mkdir ~/Desktop/temp
   cd ~/Desktop/temp
   git clone https://github.com/edwinksl/client.git faf-client
   cd faf-client
   git checkout patch
   ```

   This `patch` branch has several additional commits compared to the default `develop` branch: 1) it gets rid of the version specification for `cx_Freeze`, which was giving me installation problems if I used the `4.3.4` version previously specified, and 2) it imports `QtWebKit` from `PySide` instead of `PyQt4`.
3. Create and activate a virtualenv for Python 2 and force-upgrade `pip` just to make sure it is up-to-date:

   ```
   virtualenv venv
   source venv/bin/activate
   pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
   ```
4. Use `pip` to install `PySide` and from `requirements.txt`:

   ```
   pip install PySide
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
5. Download the `faf-uid` binary into `faf-client/lib` and make it executable:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/FAForever/uid/releases/download/v4.0.4/faf-uid -O lib/faf-uid
   chmod +x lib/faf-uid
   ```
6. `cd` to the `site-packages` directory inside the virtualenv and make appropriate symlinks:

   ```
   cd venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/ .
   ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.x86_64-linux-gnu.so .
   ```

   Note the `.` at the end of each symlink.
7. `cd` back to `faf-client` and run `python` on `src/__main__.py`:

   ```
   cd -  # this goes back to previous directory, which should be ~/Desktop/temp/faf-client
   python src/__main__.py
   ```

Comment: first off thank you! and sorry I missed the queue. I was hospitalized. I'm stuck at :
`Resolving deltas: 100% (8873/8873), done.
t@tsu:~/Desktop/temp$ git checkout patch
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
t@tsu:~/Desktop/temp$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/t/Desktop/temp/.git/
t@tsu:~/Desktop/temp$ git checkout patch
error: pathspec 'patch' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: @tatsu My bad. You need to `cd` into the `faf-client` directory first, then do `git checkout patch`.

Comment: @edwinskl yup!! and cd back up once that is done!

Comment: @edwinskl right after `pip install -r faf-client/requirements.txt
` I added `wget https://github.com/FAForever/uid/releases/download/v4.0.4/faf-uid -O ./faf-client/lib/faf-uid
` and `chmod +x ./faf-client/lib/faf-uid` then did 
`cd ./faf-client && ../venv/bin/python src/__main__.py`

as per the original tutorial forum post I built my script with : http://forums.faforever.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4507&start=200#p139389

FAF runs bbut still with an error log.

Comment: @tatsu Feel free to suggest edits! After all you have the game installed while I don't...

Comment: @edwinski I think I'm close now. perhaps the pointers aren't working since I don't have a clear package setup I'm uninstalling all previous installs. removing any libqt4 or libqt5 package seems impossible due to them being required over the whole system. can I rule them out as not interfering?

Comment: As long as you are creating your virtualenv _without_ using the `--system-site-packages` flag, then your global installs for qt4 and qt5 should not affect the virtualenv.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60833/discussion-between-edwinksl-and-tatsu).

Comment: for python3 : `(venv) t@tsu:~/faf/faf-client$ python src/__main__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/__main__.py", line 52, in <module>
    import util
  File "/home/t/faf/faf-client/src/util/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from semantic_version import Version
ImportError: No module named 'semantic_version'`

Comment: @tatsu `semantic_version` is clearly in `requirements.txt`, so this error is very unexpected. Make sure you followed every step correctly.

Comment: yup! that's it!

Answer (score 1):

## Check `~/.bashrc` for Python version override

The package you are wanting to compile requires Python version 2.7.x. Confirm that with these commands:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
>>> print PyQt4.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4']
>>>
```

That was the problem in this [Q&A](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253348&page=2).

## You are not alone with `linux error PyQt4 import QtWebKit` google search:

- [ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840318/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt4-qtwebkit)
- [cannot run spyder / ImportError: No module named QtWebKit #3200](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3200)
- [ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit' #1683](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1683)
- [Some PyQt4 applications fail to start in Yakkety due to missing PyQt4-WebKit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-qt4/+bug/1633819)
- [Python cannot import specific PyQt4 QtWebKit modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847003/python-cannot-import-specific-pyqt4-qtwebkit-modules)
- [Python 2.7.11 - ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit - Kali Linux / Debian 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604532/python-2-7-11-importerror-cannot-import-name-qtwebkit-kali-linux-debian-8)
- [PyQt4: Why I get “ImportError: No module named QtWebkit”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701619/pyqt4-why-i-get-importerror-no-module-named-qtwebkit)

Unfortunately there are alot more google results but these I believe are the most pertinent for you to read **if** the first recommendation doesn't pan out.

Comment: thank but I'm not sure if it's me who's not understanding or what but I'm using virtualenv which (I believe) is helping me not have to install python2 locally. given that i shouldn't have to worry about python3 meddling with anything. correct me if I completely missed the mark here